# Batch processing of string that is the output of command exection

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

Im trying to write batch file that executes a command line file, which outputs a big xml file.
that xml file contains unique characters of new-line or carriage-return which I want to remove, and then, when its done, write it to a file.
I know how to redirect output to a file, via '>':
So I can output my command result to a file like:
exec.exe [args] > file.txt
The problem is that I want to remove \r,\n from it, so I thought exporting the file to a variable and then to write it to a file at the end..I found this function:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %A IN ('exec.exe [args]') DO SET Variable=%A
```

and then applying the following:

```
set A=%A:\r=%
set A=%A:\n=%
```

and then to write A's content to a file.
Of course, that didn't work and that's why Im here.
It works for testing purposes, where I set a short string or 'echo ..' to test the function, but my program output is probably containing special characters, so its not working well.
the output contains `<?xml version="1.0" encod` but when I look at the output in the command-line I see:  `■< ? x m l   v e r s i o n = " 1 . 0 "` (of course there's much much more)
What am I missing here?
if there's a better way, Im all ears..I dont mind.
Im not too familiar with windows shell scripting and thats what I found on the internet.

Comment: Your file is in unicode format it seems.  I'm not sure if it handles Unicode but repl.bat to be found here is a native way to remove crlf pairs - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855

Comment: I tried many variations but nothing seemed to worked. just to verify if its unicode related issue or just misuse, How am I supposed to run this tool?

Comment: `type file.txt | repl "\r\n" "" m >file2.txt` <--- try this, it works here in a plain text file anyway to remove crlf.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the 'm' flag. Thanks. Do you know how I can instead of outputing it to a file, to output it into a variable?

Comment: I added the info as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the helper batch file repl.bat from - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "file.txt" ^| repl "\r\n" "" m ') do set "variable=%%a"
```

The variable is limited to 8KB of text.